# Get original image size after UIPinchGestureRecognizer pinch in and out

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, scale, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I would like to return the original image size after I use pinch gesture to zoom in or out.

What I have found the similar answer is

[How to get original image when we zoom in and zoom out the image in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139184/how-to-get-original-image-when-we-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-the-image-in-ios),

it uses scrollView. Not exactly what I need.

Here is my code, It's a gesture response sent by #selector

```
func respondToGesture(_ gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Void {

    if let pinch = gesture as? UIPinchGestureRecognizer {

        if let img = pinch.view as? UIImageView {

           img.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: pinch.scale, y: pinch.scale)

           if pinch.state == .ended
           {
               img.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: (1 / pinch.scale), y: (1 / pinch.scale))
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope to get some suggestions!! Thanks~

Comment: Try `img.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity` after your zoom

Comment: @MikeAlter, Thanks man, it works fine.

Comment: Welcome , I think I should post answer from now onwards  :D

Comment: And I will be happy to accept your answer. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to reset the size of your image

```
yourImage.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I also find a alternative solution. The transform scale default is 1, just set CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1) to my imageView.